# Como criar OAuth2 Rediret URI usando DropBox API no C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Não estou conseguindo conectar no `DropBox` usando uma `Console Application` do `C#` e tentei criar um `Redirect URIs` no perfil do meu `app` no site da `Dropbox`, mas não entendo muito.

No meu app, tenho http cadastrado

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento executar a aplicação pelo Visual Studio, obtenho erro de autenticação.

Tenho o código a seguir

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken))
        {
            this.GetAccessToken();
        }
        else
        {
            this.GetFiles();
        }
    }

    private void GetAccessToken()
    {
        var login = new DropboxLogin("wbjcj6pa94berli", appKey, "https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/info/wbjcj6pa94berli", false, false);
        login.Owner = this;
        login.ShowDialog();

        if (login.IsSuccessfully)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken = login.AccessToken.Value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error...");
        }
    }

    private void GetFiles()
    {

    }
}
```

A verdade é que não sei o que colocar nesse `URI`, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

existe uma aplicação de exemplo no github do dropbox para mostrar o uso do SDK no console application, também existem outros exemplos para MVC e para Apps do Windows 10:

[DropBox_SimpleTest](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleTest)

Aparentemente ele usou uma HttpClient e uma página HTML para obter o token via JS, veja se o exemplo dos caras te ajuda em usar o SDK. Você pode encontrar mais detalhes da documentação do SDK aqui:

[DropBox DotNet SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet)